# Can I remove the S3 bucket from my Elastic Beanstalk deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Yesterday I hosted my basic web app in `Elastic Beanstalk`, which works fine. Now each time I deploy the app by running `eb deploy`, it creates a `zip` file which is also uploaded (together with logs) to S3. Since I have a basic app, I don't want those zip stored in S3. Is it safe enough to delete the S3 bucket from `Elastic Beanstalk`?

Note:
I am using `Single-instance Environment`

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.S3.html

Not sure if the next time you do a deployment the S3 bucket will be recreated.

Comment: Can I store my media files in ec2 runs on the elastic beanstalk, will it be lost if auto-scaling launches new instance?

Comment: You can store images on your ec2 instance, but if scaling triggers those stored images will not be present on the newly created instance.